# Where are Java archive file structure Specifications?

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, war, ear

I'm completely mystified that I can't (easily!) find Oracle's **latest** reference specifications for JAR, WAR and EAR file structures. By this I mean:

JARs

- File structure for JAR
- Contents and structure of `MANIFEST-INF`
- Schema for latest version `MANIFEST.MF`

WARs

- File structure for a WAR
- Contents and structure of `MANIFEST-INF`
- Contents and structure of `WEB-INF`
- Schema for latest version of `web.xml` or any other config files

EARs

- File structure for an EAR
- Schema for latest version of `application.xml` and any other config files

Not only can I not find any of these items, I can't even find something off the Oracle site (docs.oracle.*) entitled "WAR File Specification", "EAR File Specification" or their likes.  Am I completely missing something here?

The search results I do find are for **servlet** specifications, and *old* versions of servlets at that (2.2, etc.).

**I'm looking for the definitive URLs that tell me *exactly* how I need to structure and configure my JARs, WARs and EARs according to the *latest* specs.** Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I assume you meant META-INF and not MANIFEST-INF...)

- JARs:

  Latest is Java7, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html for all of the three listed above:

  - Contents and structure of META-INF: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#The_META-INF_directory
  - File structure for JAR: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Intro
  - Schema for latest version MANIFEST.MF: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Section-Specification

- WARs

  - Structure and contents see: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-2.4-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/
  - Schema for web.xml: http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd

- EARs

  - Structure and contents is union of above, for deployment spec see: http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=088
  - Schema for application.xml: http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd

All these specs are quite "normalized", i.e. distributed and referencing various other sources. Since Oracle took over Sun all the links are in the same lousy state as all the other Oracle documentation :-/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

Is [Packaging Applications - The Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaby.html) what you seek?

**Update**

I normally hesitate to post links I found from the Wikipedia pages, but some of these look like the latest specifications (Java 6) and are quite detailed.

- [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29)

  - [Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html)
  - [File specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/index.html)
- [WAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_%28Sun_file_format%29)

  - [Servlet 2.5 WAR Schema](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd)
- [EAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAR_%28file_format%29)

  - [Packaging Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaby.html) (same as above)

[Java EE : XML Schemas for Java EE Deployment Descriptors](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/) is tagged as December 10th, 2009 but states that it is the latest version.

Comment: Thanks @David (+1) but that page is about 20% of what I'm looking for. Compare that page to the list I gave in my original question: (1) it talks about the different package types and their extensions, and shows an *example* of an EAR file, but does not provide a link to the EAR file *specification*. (2) It doesn't show examples (let alone specs) for JARs, EJBs or WARs. This link is on the right track to what I'm looking for, but is just as "lacking" in full-fledged documentation as all the other links I've found in my own searches. But thanks again for taking the time to help me!

Comment: @4herpsand7derpsago - I assume you checked all the external links from the Wikipedia pages, yes? It's annoying that none of the pages I'm finding have any indication of how old they are--a date or version number would be great.

Comment: Yes - I've combed all of them over and then some. Like you said, nothing indicating **latest** versions. I'm just shocked that a community as sophisticated as Java would have overlooked specifying their own deployment structures!

Comment: I added more links, but they're just pulled from the more promising-looking external links on the Wikipedia pages. :(

Comment: Probably not worth mentioning but the [Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html) and [File Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/index.html) links you provided can be changed to [Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html) and [File Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/index.html) to the docs in Java 7. Although they seem to be identical anyway.

Comment: Yes but these are just for JAR. There are two other archives I'm interested in (as the original question and bounty description specify): WARs and EARs. I'm awarding the bounty to someone who can give me the whole enchillada.